component is re-rendering after receiving new data from server
I'm trying update my chats list. I'm receiving an object from server using "onSnapshot" query method of firestore  and these object represents users, groups and channels. Then I'm combining these object using Object.assign method and then turning them into array so I can use map. The problem is when other users deletes me from their group, that group is not vanished in chats list.
Receiving groups data from server
{
group1: {...},
group2: {...},
}

Receiving groups data from server after deletion
{
group1: {...},
}

export default function List(){

  const [chats, setChats] = useState([]);
  const [groups, setGroups] = useState([]);
  const [channels, setChannels] = useState([]);
  const currentUser = auth.currentUser;

useEffect(() => {
      const getChats = () => {
        const fetchUsers = onSnapshot(
          doc(db, "userChats", currentUser.uid),
          (doc) => {
            if (doc.data()) {
              setChats(doc.data());
            }else{
              setChats([])
              
            }
          }
        );

        const fetchGroups = onSnapshot(
          doc(db, "userGroups", currentUser.uid),
          (doc) => {
            if (doc.data()) {
              setGroups(doc.data());
            }else{
              setGroups([])
              }
          }
        );

        const fetchChannels = onSnapshot(
          doc(db, "userChannels", currentUser.uid),
          (doc) => {
            if (doc.data()) {
              setChannels(doc.data());
            }else{
              setChannels([])
            }
          }
        );
        return () => {
          fetchUsers();
          fetchGroups();
          fetchChannels();
        };
      };
      currentUser.uid && getChats();
  }, [currentUser.uid]);

 return (
      <div className="List">
        {Object.entries(Object.assign(chats, groups, channels))
          ?.sort((a, b) => b[1].date - a[1].date)
          ?.map((chat) => (
          <Chats
              chatVal={chat}
              key={chat[0]}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    )
}


Why do you start the data fetching in the cleanup callback of your useEffect?
